# How can I determine when a UICollectionViewCell is displayed?

Tags: ios, uikit, uicollectionview

I'd like to know when a `UICollectionViewCell` is displayed on the actual screen.  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is insufficient, as the cell isn't actually seen at this point.  `didEndDisplayingCell` is insufficient, as it gets called when the cell is removed from view.

`UITableViewDelegate` has a `willDisplayCell` method that I've found useful for similar stuff in the past, but it doesn't appear to exist in `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

How can I determine when the cell is brought on to the screen?

Answer (score 6):

Make a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`.  Override its `didMoveToWindow` method:

```
- (void)didMoveToWindow {
    if (self.window != nil) {
        // I am now in the window's view hierarchy and thus “on screen”.
    }
}
```

Technically, the cell could still be not visible, either because it's outside the window's visible bounds, or because it's covered by another view.  But normally neither of those will be the case.

Note also that if a cell is reused, it might not get removed from and re-added to the view hierarchy.  The collection view can just change the cell's frame.  (I know `UITableView` does this with table view cells as of iOS 6.0.)  In that case, you won't receive a `didMoveToWindow` message when the cell gets re-used for another item.

If you explain *why* you want to know when a cell is displayed, we might be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: To start with, I'm just looking for an analytics event so I can compare views of cells to different actions.  But I'm also thinking about some creative animations that I don't want to start until the cell is actually visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

`-[UICollectionView visibleCells]` returns a NSArray of all cells visible on screnn

Comment: This might be part of the solution, but there's no good place that I can determine to call visible cells.  I could do it during scroll events, but then I have to keep track of what cells I already determined to be visible... there's a lot of complexity there that I don't think would be viable.

Comment: this may report cells that are not on screen.